# Definition of a Partial Order (In: Kanamori, The Higher Infinite)

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, forcing

I have a question regarding a definition in Kanamori's book on page 136. (it's the beginning of the subsection about Random Reals)

Let $\mathcal{B}^{\star} = \{X \in \mathcal{B} \ \lvert \ X \ \text{is not null} \}$ where $\mathcal{B}$ denotes the Borel-Sigma-algebra.
One defines the forcing partial order for $p,q \in \mathcal{B}^{\star}$ by:

$p \leq q \leftrightarrow p \subseteq q$

Then there is the following exercise:

(a) for $p,q \in \mathcal{B}^{\star} \ p$ and $q$ are incompatible iff $p \cap q$ is null.

(b) $\mathcal{B}^{\star}$ has the $\omega_1$-chain condition.

My question: in my opinion there is a mistake in the definition of the partial order. Shouldn't it be $p \leq q \leftrightarrow p \supseteq q$?

Thank you very much for any help in advance.

Comment: Kanamori's definition is correct: Unlike Cohen forcing in which 'larger partial function' has more information, 'smaller' conditions in Random forcing has more information in the sense that it specifies more about the random real we are adding.

Comment: (You should know that $p\le q$ in the standard forcing notion means $p$ has more information than $q$. It is different from what domain theorists or Shelah use, in which larger condition has more information.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer! I could solve exercise (a) with my definition of the partial order. But I don't understand how to do it with Kanamori's definition of the partial order. Could someone help me with this question?

Comment: It follows from the definition: If $p\cap q$ is null, then no element of $\mathcal{B}^\star$ are subsets of $p$ and $q$ simultaneously. Be careful that we only consider elements of $\mathcal{B}^\star$, so we can ignore null subsets even if they exist.

Comment: Thank you for your help. That was also my approach. So I think I understood the partial ordering correctly and my problem was related to your second comment about standard forcing notion. Now it's clear. Thanks again!

Comment: In the early days of forcing, $p\leq q$ invariably meant that $q$ had more information than $p$ (or the same amount), which makes sense in the context of partial orders. When the Boolean-valued model approach was developed, people typically did it the other way around: $p \leq q$ meant that $q$ had *less* information than $p$ (or the same amount). The latter approach now seems to be more common (unfortunately, in my opinion, but the choice is ultimately just a matter of convention). (continued…)

Comment: … Because of the resulting confusion (as in OP's question), some people took to writing $\;p\Vdash q\;$ for $p$ having at least as much information as $q,$ in an attempt to avoid the notational issue, but I don't think that ever caught on.